# Not able access elements inside frames in IE, but works fine in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, frame

I am using Selenium webdriver to automate a web application, that has many frames.

The elements inside frame are not getting identified when I run my scripts in IE,and I get an exception "**Unable to find element with link text == testing**". But this works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

I went through many related discussion, and tried the following work arounds, but they dint help.

- Inserted wait statement before and after switching the frame.
- Disabled proxy setting for IE.
  Modified IE setting to display both secure and non secure contents
- Checked 'Allow active contents to run in files on my computer' check box under Internet options -> Advanced -> security in IE settings.

I use,

Selenium webdriver version 2.35.0.0
IE version: 7
Programming language: c#

**Note:**

- The application has dynamic name and id for frames, hence I have used index for switching the frames.

I tried saving the application opened in chrome and IE as a html page. When I open the saved html page using a browser,

- The one saved from chrome shows all the elements inside the frame.
- The one saved from IE doesn't show any elements inside the frame.

It would be great if I get a solution to handle elements inside the frames.

Am not able to provide the full html code, but have attached the screenshot of a part of html code.

I tried saving the complete html page using Chrome and IE. And I do observe a difference in them.

This is the snapshot of html code that is saved from chrome. Here I do see "**< div class="mocha**"  division, that has the frame.

[image]

This is the snapshot of html code that is saved from IE. Here I do not see "**< div class="mocha**"  division, and also "**< iframe >** ".

[image]

I doubt, if this might be the cause for the problem. Let me know, if I had to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I am using index to locate frames and link text to locate elements inside frame. I am able to switch to the frame successfully without any error message, but am getting an error when I try to click on the element inside the frame after 'SwitchTo()' statement. I have added the snap shot of the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that, for some reason identifying the frames using Index was not working properly in IE. This seems to be an issue related to application’s behavior with the IE browser. Hence we came up with the following solution to overcome this issue.

Steps: 
1. Fetch all the frames in the page (using its class) as a list.
2. Iterate through the list to fetch the name of each frame in an array.
3. Then switch to the corresponding frame using frame name saved in the array.